# Redirect to one page and send post info to another

Tags: php, curl

I would like to have a form on a page that after submitting sends the person to a thank you page, but I would like to send the data from the form to another .php file on a remote server. I've used the action to send the info as a post directly to the remote server and it works just fine, but for security I don't want the location on the remote to be seen in any code. The solution I was working on is after a submit, the form action would send you to a .php that would send the post info to the remote via cURL. Which is where it goes down hill. I'm not bent on using cURL, just the only thing I read that sounded like it could work. So to recap if that came out confusing; person hits submit, they go to a .php that says "your a wonderful person," but it also sends the info in the post to a remote server while only showing the location of the remote in the php so it's not visible in code.

My html that has the form on it:

```
<form action="landing.php" method="post">
Client:<input name="client" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30">
    <br />
Test1:<input name="test1" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30">
    <br />
Test2:<input name="test2" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30">
    <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which goes to this page:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('client' => 'Foo', 'test1' => '123', 'test2' => '987');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://MyServer/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
?>
Thank You etc.
```

And it doesn't work... I'm new to cURL so that may be horribly off for what I'm trying to do. My main thing is to hide the remote's location.

Am I on the right track?
Is this possible?

Comment: have you enable curl ????????????????

Comment: What is the error you get.? is curl installed.?

Comment: I checked my error log and I had nothing for today. I'm on Bluehost and they say the have cURL enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Curl is enable or Not

After posting, try to grab the output from Curl

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path/to/form");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'foo' => 'foo foo foo',
    'bar' => 'bar bar bar',
    'baz' => 'baz baz baz'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: I'm testing this on a bluehost server and they say they are cURL enabled. For testing I'm also only sending the cURL to a local file on the same server just to test it so I'm using "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "form.php");". You also mentioned trying to grab the output of cURL, how whould I do that?

Comment: check the server log also, you may something useful there

Comment: so should I echo $info to see if it gives me anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one more alternative to :-

1. Use can store your data on session.
2. Then redirect to the page.

Hope this information will help you.

Or there is one more solution,  you can use below code to redirect to the new page:

```
<?php
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:http://MyServer/test.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit;
?>
```

Thanks and Regards
Pushkar

Answer (score 0):

First of go through [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Refer this [link](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) for posting data.
As you said "My main thing is to hide the remote's location", you can use database in this situation. save your remote locations in one of table and retrieve it whenever you want.

Try this to solve your current issue.

```
<?php
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://MyServer/test.php';
$data = array('client' => 'Foo', 'test1' => '123', 'test2' => '987');

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to `POSTFIELDS` as a string like this

```
$data = 'client=Foo&test1=123&test2=987'
```

to get the return data add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$returnText = curl_exec($ch);
$data= curl_getinfo($ch);
```

if you wanna use it as an array please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.